# exit from javascript interval after some condition

Tags: javascript

if I have repeatable function on every 1.5 sec how can I exit on some condition like this

```
 $interval(function () {
            if (a <= 35) {
                ...
            } else {
                // break up interval
                // exit                     
            }
        }, 1500);
```

Comment: Depends on what `$interval` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var interval = $interval(function () {
                if (a <= 35) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    // break up interval
                    // exit
                    $interval.cancel(interval) //this is what you can do                     
                }
            }, 1500);
```

Refer [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)